# "Tore it in small pieces" vs. "tore it into small pieces."

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Example sentence:

> He tore the paper **in/into** four pieces.

Google Ngrams [says](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tore%20it%20into%20small%20pieces%2C%20tore%20it%20in%20small%20pieces%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctore%20it%20into%20small%20pieces%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctore%20it%20in%20small%20pieces%3B%2Cc0) that the *into* version is more common. So the *in* version isn't idiomatic? Or it's equally correct?

Comment: Your own NGram chart shows at least *hundreds*, if not *thousands* of instances of the (admittedly, *less common*) version *tore it **in** small pieces*. Why would you ask if it's "idiomatic" when you can see that's it's very obviously in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you tear it, it's **in** one piece.

You tear it **into** pieces.

When you've finished, it is **in** four pieces.

Answer (score 0):

> He tore the paper **into** four pieces.

**Into** sounds more natural. It's neither idiomatic nor equally correct since *in* is used for indicating things inside of "something."

While **into** refers to places something physically inside something else just like *in*, but it can also be used for several different other things such as movement, direction, location, etc.